# Location for a Phoenix helper in a hex package

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I created an alternative `phx.gen.html` which creates templates with TailwindCSS. It works fine. I'd like to share it by creating a Hex package `phx_tailwind_generators`. Here is what I have so fare:

```
$ phx_tailwind_generators:main> tree
.
├── README.md
├── lib
│   ├── phx_tailwind_generators.ex
├── mix.exs
├── priv
│   └── templates
│       └── tailwind.gen.html
│           ├── controller.ex
│           ├── controller_test.exs
│           ├── edit.html.eex
│           ├── form.html.eex
│           ├── index.html.eex
│           ├── new.html.eex
│           ├── show.html.eex
│           └── view.ex
└── test
    ├── phx_tailwind_generators_test.exs
    └── test_helper.exs
```

In those templates I use the `tailwind_error_tag/2` helper which is defined here:

```
defmodule ExampleWeb.TailwindHelper do
  use Phoenix.HTML
  import ExampleWeb.ErrorHelpers

  @doc """
  Generates tag for inlined form input errors.
  """
  def tailwind_error_tag(form, field) do
    Enum.map(Keyword.get_values(form.errors, field), fn error ->
      content_tag(:p, translate_error(error),
        class: "mt-2 text-sm text-red-500",
        phx_feedback_for: input_name(form, field)
      )
    end)
  end
end
```

But how do I store this helper definition in the hex package? How do I rename `defmodule ExampleWeb.TailwindHelper do` in a way that it will work in the target system?

The repo:
https://github.com/wintermeyer/tailwind_phx_generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for users of your package to use this helper, they will need to import the module in the `def view` section of their `myapp_web.ex` file. Name the module as fitting for your project and in your Readme give them the instructions. An example project you can check out would be: https://github.com/ikeikeikeike/phoenix_html_simplified_helpers.

Quote from their Readme:

> 3 phoenix_html_simplified_helpers need to import(use) your Phoenix project. The following description is adding 'use syntax' into web.ex.
>
> ```
> def view do
>   quote do
>     use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates"
>
>     # Import convenience functions from controllers
>     import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_csrf_token: 0, get_flash: 2, view_module: 1]
>
>     # Use all HTML functionality (forms, tags, etc)
>     use Phoenix.HTML
>     use Phoenix.HTML.SimplifiedHelpers  # <- this line.
>
>     import MyApp.Router.Helpers
>     import MyApp.ErrorHelpers
>     import MyApp.Gettext
>   end
> end
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are after `eex` templating the sources. See how phoenix does it for e. g. [context template](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/priv/templates/phx.gen.context/context.ex).

Then you need to process it [as shown here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/mix/phoenix.ex#L41). In a nutshell, it’ll be all about calling [`EEx.eval_file/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html#eval_file/3).

```rb
Mix.Generator.create_file(target, EEx.eval_file(source, binding))
```