# helper function within a hex package

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to create a hex package which provides a scaffold generator for the Phoenix Framework which uses [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindui.com) instead of Milligram.

It's up in the cloud. All but one little thing works:
https://github.com/wintermeyer/phx_tailwind_generators

That one little thing I can't solve. In `Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Tailwind` (which started as a copy of the default scaffold generator) I call `error/1` which normally looks like this:

```
defp error(field) do
  ~s(<%= error_tag f, #{inspect(field)} %>)
end
```

But for Tailwind CSS I need the `mt-2 text-sm text-red-500` class for this to work. So I thought of creating a new `tailwind_error_tag/2` helper function which would look like this:

```
defp tailwind_error_tag(form, field) do
  Enum.map(Keyword.get_values(form.errors, field), fn error ->
    content_tag(:p, translate_error(error),
      class: "mt-2 text-sm text-red-500",
      phx_feedback_for: input_name(form, field)
    )
  end)
end
```

But that doesn't work because I don't know how to access this function as a helper from within the hex package.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does the answer on this question work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591612/location-for-a-phoenix-helper-in-a-hex-package

Answer (score 0):

Your helper function would not need to be generated every time, but rather only once by the user of your library in a separate `install` task, that puts the `tailwind_error_helper.ex` somewhere or just simply included in your `lib` folder (which will make you library a runtime dependency rather than only a development dependency).
From there you can make the helper available to the template by importing it in you view like this:

```
# if you put it into a generated module in an install step in the web module
import <%= inspect context.web_module %>.TailwindErrorHelper, only: [tailwind_error_tag: 2]

# or if you add it to you library module
import PhxTailwindGenerators, only: [tailwind_error_tag: 2]
```